# Jenkins: distinguish CI build from scheduled build

Tags: jenkins

All my Jenkins jobs are triggered both by a Github webhook, but also via a scheduled build one per week. The build process is heavily cached to make the webhook CI builds finish quickly.

I would like to add a line to my build script which wipes the cache during the weekly scheduled build, and make it build from scratch. Is there a variable in the build script to identify if a build was triggered by a webhook or schedule?

Comment: Are your builds pipeline builds?

Comment: No, just a freestyle build script.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [envInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin#EnvInjectPlugin-BuildCauses) will give you what you need?

> This plugin also exposes the cause of the current build as an
>   environment variable. A build can be triggered by multiple causes at
>   the same time e.g. an SCM Change could have occurred at the same time
>   as a user triggers the build manually.
>
> The build cause is exposed as a comma separated list:

```
BUILD_CAUSE=USERIDCAUSE, SCMTRIGGER, UPSTREAMTRIGGER, MANUALTRIGGER
```

> In addition, each cause is exposed as a single envvariable too:

```
BUILD_CAUSE_USERIDCAUSE=true
BUILD_CAUSE_SCMTRIGGER=true
BUILD_CAUSE_UPSTREAMTRIGGER=true
BUILD_CAUSE_MANUALTRIGGER=true
```